# Integrated the Unity3D code into native iOS application but getting this error VideoBackgroundConfig on application launch

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have integrated the Unity code into the iOS native application by following this blog https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5.
And as suggested in the blog i am trying to initialize **UnityAppController** object in the launch of my native application AppDelegate class.
After doing all, in my application launch i am getting the following error **VideoBackgroundConfig with screen size of zero received, skipping config step cameraDeviceGetVideoMode**.

**

```
VideoBackgroundConfig with screen size of zero received, skipping config step
Trackable UserDefinedTarget lost
    UnityEngine.GUI:INTERNAL_CALL_DoWindow(Int32, Rect&, WindowFunction, GUIContent, GUIStyle, GUISkin, Boolean, Rect&)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.GUI:INTERNAL_CALL_DoWindow(Int32, Rect&, WindowFunction, GUIContent, GUIStyle, GUISkin, Boolean, Rect&)
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
System.Func`2:EndInvoke(IAsyncResult)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Vuforia.DefaultTrackableEventHandler:OnTrackingLost()
Vuforia.DefaultTrackableEventHandler:OnTrackableStateChanged(Status, Status)
System.Func`2:EndInvoke(IAsyncResult)
Vuforia.TrackableBehaviour:RegisterTrackableEventHandler(ITrackableEventHandler)
Vuforia.DefaultTrackableEventHandler:Start()
UnityEngine.GUI:INTERNAL_CALL_DoWindow(Int32, Rect&, WindowFunction, GUIContent, GUIStyle, GUISkin, Boolean, Rect&)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1:set_Item(Int32, T)
Vuforia.WordResultImpl:get_CurrentStatus()
System.Array:Sort(T[], Int32, Int32, IComparer`1)
```

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)

cameraDeviceGetVideoMode
cameraDeviceGetVideoMode**

I can see that this is crashing inside Unity3D code on this **UnityPlayerLoop()** method.

Unity version: 5.4.0f3
Unity scripting backend: il2cpp
Xcode: 7.2.1

Can anyone help me that why am i getting this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you think it would be useful to post what Unity version you are using?

Comment: Unity version: 5.4.0f3  Unity scripting backend: il2cpp  Xcode: 7.2.1

Comment: Go to `Windows`->`Lightning`  then `Lightmaps` tab, Uncheck `Auto` then press the build button. Upload to iOS and try it again.